# Coredata delete rule confusion, xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I have a Core Data relationship between two entities, which is like this:

```
Entity A                        Entity B
aRelationship <-------------->> bRelationship
```

With the delete rule set to cascade.

Maybe I have this wrong, but I thought that if the delete rule for both of these relationships was set to "Cascade", then when did the following...

```
[context deleteObject:EntityA];
```

...it would also delete all the of the Entity B's associated with it. However when I log all of my entity B's it would seem that I am mistaken.

Could someone please shed some light on my confusion?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

While it's not immediately apparent in the graphical data model editor each recipocal relationship i.e. each

```
<-->
```

...is really two separate relationship each with its own delete rule. Delete rules are activate when an object of the entity with the delete rule is deleted.

So, if in the data model editor you have two entities `Alpha` and `Beta` with a relationship:

```
Alpha.betas<-->>Beta.alpha
```

… then you really have two relationships like so:

```
Alpha.betas--(delete rule)-->>Beta.alpha
Beta.alpha--(delete rule)-->Alpha.betas
```

You ***never*** want to set up a delete rule like this:

```
Alpha.betas--(cascade)-->>Beta.alpha
Beta.alpha--(cascade)-->Alpha.betas
```

… because deleting any one `Beta` instance will delete the associate `Alpha` object which will trigger the deletion of all related `Beta` objects. Depending on the details of your data model, a reciprocal cascade can delete a big chunk of you data by accident.

What you really want is:

```
Alpha.betas--(cascade)-->>Beta.alpha
Beta.alpha--(nullify)-->Alpha.betas
```

Now, when you delete the `Alpha` object, it will delete all associated `Beta` objects.

When a cascade is blocked, it is usually a problem with a required relationship. Can't tell for certain without details of the data model.

Comment: Quick question, when I run `[context deleteObject:EntityA];` this will ensure that all betas are deleted right, if i have it set up just as you have in the last snipit of code?

Comment: Assuming there isn't something else blocking the delete.

Comment: But what if I delete all Betas? How to make Alpha delete automatically in such case?

Comment: Just a thought: Set minimum 1 for the relationship and the delete will fail for the last beta. Handle the error by deleting the related Alpha. Not sure if it works this way though.

Comment: Now, when you delete the Alpha object, it will delete all associated Beta objects. but suppose i dont want to delete the Beta object if it is associated in another object.how is this possible??

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what delete rules are you using.

Here is what Apple said in their document:

> "When you delete a managed object it is important to consider its
>   relationships and in particular the delete rules specified for the
>   relationships. If all of a managed object's relationship delete rules
>   are Nullify, then for that object at least there is no additional work
>   to do (you may have to consider other objects that were at the
>   destination of the relationship—if the inverse relationship was either
>   mandatory or had a lower limit on cardinality, then the destination
>   object or objects might be in an invalid state). If a relationship
>   delete rule is Cascade, then deleting one object may result in the
>   deletion of others. If a rule is Deny, then before you delete an
>   object you must remove the destination object or objects from the
>   relationship, otherwise you will get a validation error when you save.
>   If a delete rule is No Action, then you must ensure that you take
>   whatever steps are necessary to ensure the integrity of the object
>   graph."

The link of “Relationship Delete Rules.”: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW1